# Row in Matrix A with not multiple ocurrences

Tags: python

I have to create a function, this have to return true if a row in that matrix have no multiple ocurrences and false otherwise. This have to be done by loops, then create the same function with recursion.

I just get to iterate into the matrix but do not really understand how to check if those vales are repeated or not.

I am working with python, the module is "Data Structures and Algorithms"

```
A = [ [8,4,2], [3,6,3], [7,4,1] ] 
def noRepeatedRow(A)
    for i in range (0, len(A)):
        for j in range (0, len(A[i])):
print(noRepeatedRow(A))
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking down the problem, writing some pseudocode? Can you clarify the requirements, too? Are you checking for repeated rows, or repeated numbers within rows?

Answer (score 0):

This the algorithm:

```
def IsnonrepeatedRow(A):
  count = 0
  for i in range(len(A)):
    for x in range (i+1, len(A)):
      for j in range(len(A[0])):
        if A[i][j] // A[x][j] == 0:
         count += 1
      if count == len(A[0]):
        return True
      count = 0
return False
```